# scan ble beacon on Samsung gear s2: result null for RSSI reading

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-gear-s2

I'm trying to scan a Sensorberg BLE beacon with my Samsung Gear S2. I would like to get the `txpowerlvl` by reading the advertisement data. I'm using Tizen Studio with updated firmware on my Gear S2.

The scan sometimes detects the `txpowerlvl` but sometimes produces zero results (the `txpowerlvl` is `null`).  I have tried to simulate Beacon signals from my iPhone and it could detect them, but the `txpowerlvl` is always null.

I presume there is a problem with Bluez or its API. Some have had success with [CSR bluetooth boards](http://www.csr.com/), but why doesn't it work with my Sensorberg beacon (or my iPhone)?

**This is my main.js**

```
var BLEconnect = document.getElementById("BLEconnect");
var BLEstopscan = document.getElementById("BLEstopscan");
var BLEdisconnect = document.getElementById("BLEdisconnect");
var remoteDevice = null;
var adapter = tizen.bluetooth.getLEAdapter();
var myhandler1 = function () {
function connectFail(error)
{
 console.log("Failed to connect to device: " + e.message);
}
function connectSuccess()
{
     console.log("Connected to device");
}
function showGATTService(service, indent)
{
 if (indent === undefined)
 {
 indent = "";
 }
     console.log(indent + "Service " + service.uuid + ". Has " + service.characteristics.length
     + " characteristics and " + service.services.length + " sub-services.");
 for (var i = 0; i < service.services.length; i++)
 {
 showGATTService(service.services[i], indent + " ");
 }
}   

function onDeviceFound(device)
{
 if (remoteDevice === null)
 {
 remoteDevice = device;
 console.log("Found device name: " + device.name + " txpowerlevel: " +         device.txpowerlevel + " . Connecting...");
 device.connect(function connectSuccess()
 {      
     console.log("Connected to device");

     var i = 0, service = null;
     var serviceUUIDs = remoteDevice.uuids;
     console.log("remoteDevice.uuids: "+ serviceUUIDs);
     console.log("remoteDevice.uuids.length :"+ serviceUUIDs.length);
     for (i; i < serviceUUIDs.length; i++)
     {
     service = remoteDevice.getService(serviceUUIDs[i]);
     showGATTService(service);
     }      

 } , connectFail);      
 }
 adapter.stopScan();
}
adapter.startScan(onDeviceFound);   
}
var myhandler2 = function () {
remoteDevice.disconnect();
}
var myhandler3 = function () {
adapter.stopScan()
}
BLEconnect.addEventListener("click", myhandler1, false);
BLEdisconnect.addEventListener("click", myhandler2, false);
BLEstopscan.addEventListener("click", myhandler3, false);
window.onload = function() {

document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
 if (e.keyName === "back") {
try {
tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
} catch (ignore) {}
}
});
```

This is my sdb dblog

```
 I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-adapter-le.c: bluetooth_stop_le_discovery(131) >←[32m Sync Request => type=BT_BLUEZ_SERVICE, fn=BT_STOP_LE_DISCOVERY(0x12) ←[0m
E/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-adapter.c: bt_adapter_le_stop_scan(2398) > NOT_IN_PROGRESS(0xfe400105)
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-adapter-le.c: bluetooth_start_le_discovery(111)> ←[32m Sync Request => type=BT_BLUEZ_SERVICE, fn=BT_START_LE_DISCOVERY(0x11) ←[0m
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-common.c: __bt_le_event_proxy(2399) >Need to check 2 slots in the case
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-common.c: __bt_le_event_proxy(2429) >BLUETOOTH_EVENT_REMOTE_LE_DEVICE_FOUND
E/WRT_PLUGINS/TIZEN( 4592): BluetoothLEDevice.cpp: BluetoothLEDevice(59) > Failed to get txpower strength from scan response: -61
E/WRT_PLUGINS/TIZEN( 4592): BluetoothLEDevice.cpp: BluetoothLEDevice(63) > Failed to get txpower strength from advertise data: -61
E/WRT_PLUGINS/TIZEN( 4592): BluetoothLEDevice.cpp: BluetoothLEDevice(77) > Failed to get appearance value from scan response: -61
E/WRT_PLUGINS/TIZEN( 4592): BluetoothLEDevice.cpp: BluetoothLEDevice(81) > Failed to get appearance value from advertise data: -61
E/WRT_PLUGINS/TIZEN( 4592): BluetoothLEDevice.cpp: BluetoothLEDevice(96) > Failed to get service data list from scan response: -61
E/WRT_PLUGINS/TIZEN( 4592): BluetoothLEDevice.cpp: BluetoothLEDevice(100) > Failed to get service data list from advertise data: -61
E/WRT_PLUGINS/TIZEN( 4592): BluetoothLEDevice.cpp: BluetoothLEDevice(148) > Failed to get the service solicitation UUID list from scan response: -61
E/WRT_PLUGINS/TIZEN( 4592): BluetoothLEDevice.cpp: BluetoothLEDevice(152) > Failed to get the service solicitation UUID list from advertise data: -61
E/WRT_PLUGINS/TIZEN( 4592): BluetoothLEDevice.cpp: BluetoothLEDevice(167) > Failed to get the service service_uuids list from scan response: -61
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-device.c: bluetooth_connect_le(352) > ←[32m ###Connect LE ←[0m
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-device.c: bluetooth_connect_le(355) > ←[32m Async Request => type=BT_BLUEZ_SERVICE, fn=BT_CONNECT_LE(0x159) ←[0m
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-adapter-le.c: bluetooth_stop_le_discovery(131) >←[32m Sync Request => type=BT_BLUEZ_SERVICE, fn=BT_STOP_LE_DISCOVERY(0x12) ←[0m
W/WECONN ( 540): <__on_bt_adapter_le_advertising_state_changed_cb:1489> result(0), state(0)
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-common.c: __bt_event_proxy(2108) > BLUETOOTH_EVENT_ADVERTISING_STARTED
E/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-adapter.c: _bt_adapter_le_invoke_advertising_state_cb(2120) > No available advertiser
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-common.c: __bt_event_proxy(1751) > BLUETOOTH_EVENT_GATT_CONNECTED
E/WECONN ( 540): <_bt_gatt_client_get_service:3219> ret : -61
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-device.c: bluetooth_is_device_connected(318) > ←[32m Sync Request => type=BT_BLUEZ_SERVICE, fn=BT_IS_DEVICE_CONNECTED(0x5a) ←[0m
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: bluetooth_gatt_get_primary_services(320) > +
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-gatt.c: _bt_gatt_client_update_services(190) > Service handle[0] /org/bluez/hci0/dev_7D_4C_09_B1_16_A6/service0056
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: bluetooth_gatt_get_service_property(257) > ======> Service : c4d8e0c7-24b7-48ba-81c1-1b6280fdb3a6 [Unknown]
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-gatt.c: _bt_gatt_client_update_services(190) > Service handle[1] /org/bluez/hci0/dev_7D_4C_09_B1_16_A6/service0053
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: bluetooth_gatt_get_service_property(257) > ======> Service : 59b02dbf-ef00-4f8c-b470-51cae194d838 [Unknown]
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-gatt.c: _bt_gatt_client_update_services(190) > Service handle[2] /org/bluez/hci0/dev_7D_4C_09_B1_16_A6/service0050
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: bluetooth_gatt_get_service_property(257) > ======> Service : 00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb [Immediate Alert]
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-gatt.c: _bt_gatt_client_update_services(190) > Service handle[3] /org/bluez/hci0/dev_7D_4C_09_B1_16_A6/service0044
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: bluetooth_gatt_get_service_property(257) > ======> Service : 89d3502b-0f36-433a-8ef4-c502ad55f8dc [Apple Media Service]
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-gatt.c: _bt_gatt_client_update_services(190) > Service handle[4] /org/bluez/hci0/dev_7D_4C_09_B1_16_A6/service003a
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: bluetooth_gatt_get_service_property(257) > ======> Service : 7905f431-b5ce-4e99-a40f-4b1e122d00d0 [Apple Notification Center Service]
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-gatt.c: _bt_gatt_client_update_servic
es(190) > Service handle[5] /org/bluez/hci0/dev_7D_4C_09_B1_16_A6/service0035
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: bluetooth_gatt_get_service_property(257) > ======> Service : 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb [Device Information]
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-gatt.c: _bt_gatt_client_update_services(190) > Service handle[6] /org/bluez/hci0/dev_7D_4C_09_B1_16_A6/service002f
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: bluetooth_gatt_get_service_property(257) > ======> Service : 00001805-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb [Current Time Service]
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-gatt.c: _bt_gatt_client_update_services(190) > Service handle[7] /org/bluez/hci0/dev_7D_4C_09_B1_16_A6/service002b
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: bluetooth_gatt_get_service_propety(257) > ======> Service : 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb [Battery Service]
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-gatt.c: _bt_gatt_client_update_services(190) > Service handle[8] /org/bluez/hci0/dev_7D_4C_09_B1_16_A6/service000a
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: bluetooth_gatt_get_service_property(257) > ======> Service : d0611e78-bbb4-4591-a5f8-487910ae4366 [Unknown]
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-gatt.c: _bt_gatt_client_update_services(190) > Service handle[9] /org/bluez/hci0/dev_7D_4C_09_B1_16_A6/service0006
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: bluetooth_gatt_get_service_property(257) > ======> Service : 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb [Generic Attribute]
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-gatt.c: _bt_gatt_client_update_services(190) > Service handle[10] /org/bluez/hci0/dev_7D_4C_09_B1_16_A6/service0001
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: bluetooth_gatt_get_service_property(257) > ======> Service : 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb [Generic Access]
I/CAPI_NETWORK_BLUETOOTH( 4592): bluetooth-gatt.c: bt_gatt_client_create(2496) > GATT Client Handle is created
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: bluetooth_gatt_get_characteristics_property(654) > Characteristic : b2433de2-ef79-4168-8288-c0ef8f0fcff8 [Unknown]
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: __get_permission_flag(555) > permission = read
E/WRT_PLUGINS/TIZEN( 4592): BluetoothGATTCharacteristic.cpp: BluetoothGATTCharacteristic(48) > Watch callback couldn't be registred
I/BLUETOOTH_FRWK_API( 4592): bt-gatt-client.c: bluetooth_gatt_get_characteristics_property(654) > Characteristic : 00002a06-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb [Alert Level]
E/WRT_PLUGINS/TIZEN( 4592): BluetoothGATTCharacteristic.cpp: BluetoothGATTCharacteristic(48) > Watch callback couldn't be registred
```

**This is my console.log**

```
Found device name: Heart Rate txpowerlevel: null . Connecting... app.js:40
Connected to device app.js:44
remoteDevice.uuids: 180A,180D app.js:48
remoteDevice.uuids.length :2 app.js:49
Service 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. Has 9 characteristics and 0 sub-services. app.js:26
Service 0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. Has 3 characteristics and 0 sub-services. app.js:26
```

Comment: Please check first, Whether is there any object named txpowerlevel  exists under device variable or not .

Also check whether you add "bluetooth" and "application.launch" privileges or not in config.xml file.

Comment: Any leads regarding this? My app crashes occasionally after printing this in my log!!